# Regex in add_rewrite_tag not accepting OR operators?

Tags: permalinks, rewrite-rules, regex, rewrite-tag

I am trying to add a custom field to the post permalinks by using a combo of `add_rewrite_tag` and applying a `post_link` filter.

What I am aiming for is something like this:

```
http://example.com/%category%/%mycustomfield%/%postname%
```

I can manage to get the `%mycustomfield%` as `%psubject%` working by using

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_rewrite_tag');
function register_rewrite_tag() {  
    add_rewrite_tag( '%psubject%', '(.*)' );
}
```

However there are only a set number of `%psubject%` values.

But the regex below, which I have tested on regex testers does not work and instead redirects all posts with this link structure to the homepage as `home.php`, not even a `404` or index redirect.

```
add_rewrite_tag( '%psubject%', '(option1|option2|option3)');
```

However simply having the regex inputs below will work.

```
(option1) or (.*)
```

Such as

```
http://example.com/somecategory/option1/this-is-the-post-title
```

will show the correct post.

---

**Edit:** I have found even in Wordpress 3.6 that this issue still occurs.

It appears that by using the regex `OR` operator in the `add_rewrite_tag` function only will allow the last option of the `OR` statement, but not any before it.

Example:

```
add_rewrite_tag( '%slugname%', '(orange|apple|strawberry)');
```

Will only allow 'strawberry', despite the syntax being a standard `OR` statement.

This issue **does not occur** in other Wordpress functions such as `add_rewrite_rule`.

**Question:** How can I tell the rewrite tag to only allow a set number of strings to be accepted for the permalink?

Comment: Still have not found an answer for this, it either appears this is a bug whereby the Pipe OR operator is not working on Rewrite tags or Wordpress does not allow it. I have managed to get it working by allowing only lowercase letters but it still does not limit what word the tag can be.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what's wrong but I can suggest:

- Use [Rewrite Rules Inspector](http://wordpress.org/plugins/rewrite-rules-inspector/) or similar to see where your `%psubject%` rule is and if its pattern (`(option1|option2|option3)`) has been added correctly.
- Test `http://example.com/somecategory/option1/this-is-the-post-title` with the Inspector to see which rule matches.
- Open `http://example.com/somecategory/option1/this-is-the-post-title` (when it shows `home.php`) with the Debug Bar plugin and look at **Query String**, **Matched Rewrite Rule**, and **Matched Rewrite Query**.