# Can't change first part of URL rewrite for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting

I have successfully created a custom post type with a URL rewrite that changes URLs from:

```
domain.com/post-type/slug
```

To:

```
domain.com/some-string/custom-field-value-1/custom-field-value-2/slug
```

This is working, but there have been some changes to my project that require me to do this instead:

```
domain.com/some-string/custom-field-value-1/custom-field-value-2/slug
domain.com/some-other-string/custom-field-value-1/custom-field-value-2/slug
```

Essentially, the first part of the path needs to be dynamic so that both "some-string" and "some-other-string" are valid.

I've updated the rewrite rules to accommodate this change, and those pages do work correctly, but none of the other pages on the site (except the front page) work at all. I'm seeing the header and footer, but no content.

Here's the relevant section of my custom post type registration:

```
'rewrite' => array(
    'slug' => '%keyterms%/%community%/%address%',
    'with_front' => false,
)
```

And here's my code:

```
function inventory_rewrite_tags() {
    add_rewrite_tag('%keyterms%', '(.*)');
    add_rewrite_tag('%community%', '(.*)');
    add_rewrite_tag('%address%', '(.*)');
}
add_action('init', 'inventory_rewrite_tags');

function inventory_link_rewrite($link, $post) {
    if($post->post_type === 'inventory') {
        $community = get_field('community', $post->ID);
        $address = get_field('address', $post->ID);
        $possession_terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'possession');
        $build_type_terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'build_type');
        $ownership_terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'ownership');

        // Add keyterm
        if($ownership_terms[0]->slug == 'rental') {
            $link = str_replace('%keyterms%/', 'apartments-for-rent/', $link);
        } else {
            $link = str_replace('%keyterms%/', 'homes-for-sale/', $link);
        }

        // Add community
        if($community) {
            $link = str_replace('%community%/', $community[0]->post_name . '/', $link);
        } else {
            $link = $possession_terms ? str_replace('%community%/', $possession_terms[0]->slug . '/', $link) : $link;
        }

        // Add address
        if($address) {
            $link = str_replace('%address%/', sanitize_title($address) . '/', $link);
        } else {
            $link = $build_type_terms ? str_replace('%address%/', $build_type_terms[0]->slug . '/', $link) : $link;
        }
    }
    return $link;
}
add_filter('post_link', 'inventory_link_rewrite', 10, 2);
```

Unfortunately creating a second post type is not an option.

Comment: But ideally, the first part of the path (which is the rewrite base) should be static - i.e. `something-static/%keyterms%/` and not just `%keyterms%/`. Otherwise, you'd run into `404` errors because of rewrite conflicts.

Comment: That seems to be the case. Is there a way around it?

Comment: Sorry, I had not actually looked thoroughly on your code.. but anyway, see my answer and let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with that `add_rewrite_tag('%keyterms%', '(.*)')`, which results in rewrite conflicts because the generated rewrite rules would match `http://example.com/(anything-here)` and that `(anything-here)` can be a Page (post type `page`) *slug*, hence `http://example.com/page-slug` would not work — you wouldn't get a `404` error page, but the proper Page wouldn't be displayed, either.

So looking at your code, instead of using that `(.*)` (which matches anything), you should instead specify the *exact* value, which in your case is either `apartments-for-rent` or `homes-for-sale`:

```php
add_rewrite_tag('%keyterms%', '(apartments-for-rent|homes-for-sale)');
```

That should work, but be sure to flush the rewrite rules — just visit the permalink settings page.

### UPDATE

Sorry, I wasn't aware WordPress isn't retaining the RegEx for all rewrite rules, specifically for attachments where WordPress [removes the brackets](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.3/src/wp-includes/class-wp-rewrite.php#L1086) (`(` and `)`):

```php
// Relevant code in WP_Rewrite::generate_rewrite_rules().
$submatchbase = str_replace( array( '(', ')' ), '', $match );
```

And I know you changed the RegEx to `([aehomnprt]+s-for-[aelnrst]+)` which does work, although not as precise as the `(apartments-for-rent|homes-for-sale)`.

So apart from the alternate RegEx, you can make `(apartments-for-rent|homes-for-sale)` works like so (this code would go in the theme functions file):

```php
add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array', 'fix_inventory_rewrite_rules' );
function fix_inventory_rewrite_rules( $rules ) {
    $rules2 = [];
    $values = 'apartments-for-rent|homes-for-sale';

    $_re = $values . '/';
    $my_re = preg_quote( $_re, '/' );
    foreach ( $rules as $regex => $query ) {
        if ( preg_match( '/^' . $my_re . '/', $regex ) ) {
            $regex = str_replace( $_re, '(' . $values . ')/', $regex );
        }
        $rules2[ $regex ] = $query;
    }

    return $rules2;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the fantastic explanation! This is so close to working - now I'm only having this issue with the "apartments-for-rent" pages. If I switch the order in add_rewrite_tag to '(homes-for-sale|apartments-for-rent)', then the problem affects the "homes-for-sale" pages instead.

Comment: So based on [this question from 2013](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/107982/regex-in-add-rewrite-tag-not-accepting-or-operators), the regex OR operator in the add_rewrite_tag function will only work for the last option of the OR statement. It doesn't look like that issue has been addressed, so I spent a few hours messing around with [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/gO7yT8/17) and replaced the OR operator with what I hope will be a specific enough regular expression. It works! I'm very happy to say that the rewrite base does not need to be static. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Hey, I completely missed that issue! Thanks a lot for pointing it and I'm glad you found that alternate RegEx. But I updated the answer with another solution which you might want to *try*.. :) Btw, +1 for the question ;)

Comment: You're a genius! Your code worked perfectly, and I definitely prefer the specificity of your solution. Thank you for the update!